# Determine whether a matrix is identity matrix (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

What is the best way to determine whether a given matrix 'M' is 
equal to identity? I.e. something like:

```
if numpy.identity(3) == M:
     ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.eye` or `np.identity` will both return an identity matrix `I` of specified size. For example:

```
np.eye(3) # np.identity(3)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Assuming `M` is square and with `dtype=int`, this is how you'd want to test:

```
assert (M.shape[0] == M.shape[1]) and (M == np.eye(M.shape[0])).all()
```

Add the check to ensure `M` is square first. This returns `True` if the two 2D-arrays are identical.

Alternatively, if `M` is a float matrix, use `np.allclose` instead:

```
assert (M.shape[0] == M.shape[1]) and np.allclose(M, np.eye(M.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 5):

A problem with the `==` is it compares each element, and returns a boolean matrix.  That can't be used in the `if` context (you'll get the common `ValueError ... ambiguous` error):

```
In [238]: M=np.diag(1+np.random.random(3)*1e-10)
In [239]: M
Out[239]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
In [240]: M==np.eye(3)
Out[240]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
In [241]: np.allclose(M,np.eye(3))
Out[241]: True
```

`np.allclose` is a widely used way of comparing arrays.  It handles floats more gracefully than `==`.

Using `all` to reduce the array to a scalar is also widely used:

```
In [242]: (M==np.eye(3)).all()
Out[242]: False
```

Here I get different results because I deliberately created a float that is close, but not exactly an identity.  That's like to be the case when testing for matrix inversion case.

Comment: `==` fails because `M` has `1.0000000000124407` (and the like) instead of `1.0` (not exactly identity).

Comment: using { np.allclose } is better than { (x==y).all } because we can set the tolerance. Check { np.allclose } [documentation] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html )

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in function [**`np.equal()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) combined with [**`np.all()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) like:

```
In [242]: I = np.eye(3)
In [243]: M = np.array([[1.0, 0, 0], [0, 1.0, 0], [0, 0, 1.0]])

In [244]: np.all(np.equal(M, I))
Out[244]: True
```